# “$abc$” and “$cba$” are both divisible by $7$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $a$, $b$, and $c$ are distinct numbers . Find all $(a,b,c)$ such that the three-digit numbers “$abc$” and “$cba$” are both divisible by $7$.

$a,b,c$ are digits so if $a=1,b=2,c =3$, we have $abc = 123$ and $cba = 321$

Comment: Do a, b, c represent digits?

Comment: Yes , they represent digits.

Comment: Brute force it ?

Comment: $a \neq 0$ and $c \neq 0$, consider $100$ is a 3 digit number but $001$ is not .

Answer (score 4):

We have $7|100a+10b+c$ so $7|2a+3b+c$ (1) and $7|2c+3b+a$ (2).

Subtract (1) and (2) and obtain: $7|a-c$ (3).

From (1) and (3) we get: $7|2a+3b+c+a-c$, or $7|3(a+b)$. But, $gdc(3,7)=1$, so $7|a+b$ (4).

From (3) and (4) we get:

161 and 168 (if a=1),

252 and 259 (if a=2),

343 (if a=3),

434 (if a=4),

525 and 595 (if a=5),

616 and 686 (if a=6),

707 and 700 and 770 and 777 (if a=7),

861 and 868 (if a=8),

952 and 959 (if a=9).

Now, because $ a \neq b \neq c \neq a$, the solutions are: 168,259,861,952.

Comment: a,b,c are distinct.

Comment: sorry! I will edit my post!